# Convert WW Extract from SQLite to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I have the following SQLite statement:

```
(strftime('%j', date( s.my_time, '-3 days', 'weekday 3'))) / 7 AS ww
```

How can I accomplish this same function on s.my_time in postgresql?

Comment: `select extract(days from age(now() - '-3 days'::interval, now()))/7;  0.42857142857142857143`? Hard to say without more information on what `s.my_time` and what the result is in SQLite.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I need to provide more information. my_time is in the datetime format '2022-09-03 21:03:44'. And the desired result is the workweek as an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite:

```
select (strftime('%j', 
date( '2022-09-03 21:03:44', '-3 days', 'weekday 3'))) / 7 AS ww;
34
```

In Postgres:

```
select extract(doy from '2022-08-31'::timestamp - '3 days'::interval)::integer/7;

 ?column? 
----------
       34
```

Though if you do:

```
select to_char('2022-09-03 21:03:44'::timestamp - '3 days'::interval, 'WW');
 to_char 
---------
 35
```

You get a different week as without converting the `extract` output to `integer` you get:

```
 select extract(doy from '2022-08-31'::timestamp)/7;
      ?column?       
---------------------
 34.7142857142857143
```

Comment: I meant to ask for Oracle, not postgres which is my fault. I marked it as the best answer but if you have a solution in Oracle please feel free to add it.

Comment: I have never used Oracle nor have access to Oracle so I can't provide a definitive answer. I do know Postgres modeled a good deal of it's date/time handling to follow Oracle behavior, so it would be worth it to try the above there.